# error 405 POST ajax laravel MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: jquery, ajax, bootstrap, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo un formulario en el que intento agregar una categoria por medio de ajax y siempre que intento crear una categoria me salta error POST 405, y nunca llega a  Categoria controller y obviamente no introduce nada en la base de datos

Uso windows 7 y Xampp y todo esto es en localhost

Mis datos

```
Route::resource('categorias','categoriaController');
```

CREACATEGORIAS

```
{!! Form::open(['route' => 'admin.categorias.store','method' =>'POST','class'=>'form-horizontal']) !!}

                                    {{ csrf_field() }}

                                   <div  class="form-group">
                                          {!! Form::label('categoria', 'Categoria', ['class' => 'col-md-4 control-label']) !!}
                                        <div class="col-md-6">

                                         {!! Form::text('categoria', '', ['Crea una categoria','class'=>'form-control']) !!}


                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                      <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="bsubmit">
                                                <i class="fa fa-btn fa-user"></i> Crea tu categoria
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

FUNCION AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $('#bsubmit').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var valorCategoria = $('input[name="categoria"]').val();
        //var rutaCompleta = window.location.pathname+'/create';
    var rutaCompleta = window.location.pathname;

        $.ajax({
            url: rutaCompleta,
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {'categoria': valorCategoria},
            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') },
        })
        .done(function() {
            console.log("success");
                    var estilo = 'style="background : green; height : 30px; text-align:center; color:white; margin-top:20px "';
                    var msgnotificacion =   '<div class="alert alert-success">';
                        msgnotificacion+=   '<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>';
                        msgnotificacion+=   '<strong>REGISTRO '+valorCategoria+' CREADO CORRECTAMENTE</strong>';
                        msgnotificacion+=   '</div>';

                     $('#labelnombre').after(msgnotificacion);
                     $('#bsubmit').after('<p '+estilo+'>Categoria..:: '+valorCategoria+' ::.. </p>');

        })
        .fail(function(erroz) {
            console.log("error_"+erroz.status);
        })
        .always(function() {
            console.log("complete");
        });




    })
});
```

Los metas que tengo en la vista

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="_token" content="{!!csrf_token()!!}">
```

CategoriaController (metodo store)

```
  public function store(Request $request)
    {

        dd($request->all());
         if ($request->ajax()) :
            \App\modelos\categoria::create($request->all());

        endif;

    }
```

Comment: Cual estaría siendo el valor de la variable JS `rutaCompleta`? Es probable que aquí radique el error.

Comment: El valor de rutaCompleta, es el valor de la barra de herramientas, lo he comprobado y es correcto, me fallaba que habia puesto el metodo en create en vez de store, ya esta solucionado Gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error 405 es "Método o verbo no permitido".

Si estás usando `Route:resource(algo)` debes seguir las convenciones de Laravel, (a menos que crees tu propia generación de rutas):

Según la documentación de Laravel al respecto, la ruta `algo/create` es la que debería mostrar el formulario de creación por lo cual debe ser un GET.

La ruta que utiliza el verbo POST para guardar la información es `algo/store`.

En resumen, debes adaptar mejor tu controlador para que coincida con los verbos y rutas de `Route::resource` o agregar excepciones en el método, o no utilizarlo y definir cada ruta manual.

Aquí tienes el enlace donde muestra la tabla de equivalencias para `Route::resource`: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers

Comment: Unos momentos despues de escribir la pregunta, me di cuenta de que me habia equivocado de metodo, he probado tantas cosas, he mirado hasta la configuracion del apache y  me habia olvidado de la principal. Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. SOLUCIONADO. Saludos.